# Has anybody used waf to build Java Applications?

Tags: java, ivy, waf

Has anybody used successfully [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/)  for building java applications? Preferably on Jython? Maybe with ivy integration?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a more flexible build than ANT or Maven, but at the same time utilize Maven or Ivy repositories, you should consider [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org).

Answer (score -3):

I seriously doubt that it's being used by more than few Java folks. I suspect that people might get tempted by it when migrating some python code to Java, but that's it.

Why would someone use it vs well known/supported(manuals, IDE, tutorials) frameworks? I guess I don't have to name those web frameworks :-).

Why would a Java developer use it vs Grails, JRuby on rails, etc.

Comment: I second what @lazy said. Not sure any Java developer would ever use it.

Comment: Somehow I don't understand your answer, I'm talking about a build tool! I'm became disenchanted with ant/maven and looking for alternatives.